# load ajax guestbook into DIV

Tags: php, ajax, load

I have a dynamic web page and want to implement dynamic guestbook into DIV tag. I use this code to load the guestbook:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.diskusia').click(function () {
$("#disk").load("diskusia/index.php");
});
});
```

and it is not working. To see how the direct guestbook link work click here [Working](http://airsoftbanda.host.sk/diskusia/index.php)
and to see what happen when I use script above click here [not working](http://airsoftbanda.host.sk/test.php) - there click on walkie talkie picture to start script.

Guestbook use ajax, never need to reload page. What I need to do to make it work properly?

Comment: What about fixing those JS errors on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are Scripts loaded in the `discusia/index.php` file, which you have to load manually, too:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.diskusia').click(function () {
  // load needed js
  $.getScript('http://airsoftbanda.host.sk/diskusia/gb_ajax.js', function(){
    // load  guestbook
    $("#disk").load("diskusia/index.php", function(){
      // load content via ajax
      var pcode = '7cda7fcaf498bd8e8e4e4d05aa58e8a8';
      ajax('POST','diskusia/gb_view.php','page','1','773877aa04a367b315b5835f4b34016a');
    });
  });
});
});
```

now you've to load the css manually, too...

Comment: Thank you, it works. I find how to load CSS and implement it too. And please help me little bit more, because the whole guestbook still not working, and I am still noob. It seems that it needs to be manually load also other PHPs because pictures are not loaded also signform not working and this all is in different PHPs. There is whole guestbook to download [link](http://www.hnscripts.com/). Really thank you for your help :)

Comment: I figured out everything, only one problem now. When I click "Sign the Guestbook" the form shows only text area and smyles. No inputs, no buttons. Trying few thinks but nos sucess. Form is HTML code in index.php ....

Comment: You've got `input { display: none; }` in your styles.css ;) remove that!

Comment: Oh man, what a stupid mistake :D I was experimenting some days ago with inputs, and do not even use them but forget to delete everything in CSS from that. Sometimes is good to think easier. I think I would never try to look on my CSS and I was trying everything else :D Thank you :)